# How to render a list to template?

Tags: java, playframework, render, playframework-2.0

I want to show all users present in a database. I want to place all users in a list and then render that list to a template.

Then I want to iterate over the list of users displaying each in a `<p>` tag

```
For u in users:
 <p>u.username</p>
Endfor
```

I want to know how to retrieve the users from the database.

```
Public static Result render_f() {
  List<String> users = ask in db;
return ok(template.render(users));
```

Is the above approach reasonable? If not can I get some pointers on where to go from here?

Comment: That is indeed the good way to do it. One more suggestion, try to check out the samples included in the framework bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the basic syntax, often showed in [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Home) and [samples](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java) (check ie. `computer-database` sample

`app/models/User.java`

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    public static Finder<Long,User> find = new Finder<Long,User>(Long.class, User.class);

}
```

`app/controllers/Application.java`

```
Public static Result render_f() {
    List<User> users = User.find.all();
    return ok(template.render(users));
}
```

`template.scala.html`

```
@(users: List[User])

@for(user <- users){
   <p>user.id</p>
   <p>user.name</p>
   etc...
}
```